# Search list of IDs in a column and select the non-existent IDs

Tags: mysql

I have a list of IDs `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9` and a MySQL table as below;

```
mysql> describe tbl;
+-------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type            | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | int(5) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |       |
+-------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> select * from tbl;
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  4 |
|  8 |
+----+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

What I want to do is to find the ids from the list which doesn't exist in table.

I have tried different approaches using `IN` and `NOT IN` clauses but couldn't get the required result.

Using above example, I need the result to be `2,3,5,6,7,9` since these ids doesn't exist in table.

P.S. list of IDs is a comma separated string and I am looking forward to do it using single query.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT * FROM ints;

    +---+
    | i |
    +---+
    | 0 |
    | 1 |
    | 2 |
    | 3 |
    | 4 |
    | 5 |
    | 6 |
    | 7 |
    | 8 |
    | 9 |
    +---+
    10 rows in set (1.65 sec)

 SELECT a.* 
   FROM
      (SELECT  8 i UNION 
       SELECT  9 UNION 
       SELECT 10 UNION 
       SELECT 11 UNION 
       SELECT 12) a 
    LEFT 
    JOIN ints b 
      ON b.i = a.i 
   WHERE b.i IS NULL;
    +----+
    | i  |
    +----+
    | 10 | 
    | 11 | 
    | 12 | 
    +----+
    3 rows in set (0.06 sec)
```